# how to send message from a php web service to a specified ios device

Tags: ios, response

I have a ios device and a web service written in php. When the ios device send a request to the web service, the web service will response to that exact ios device. I don't know how can server send response to that device. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can research into each of these individual components:

1) App make a HTTP POST request to web service with a callback delegate method (ASIHttpRequest or AFNetworking)

2) Server receives request, parses it, then constructs a JSON response and return it back to the app automagically (use a web framework)

3) In your app's delegate callback method, you will parse the JSON data as a NSDictionary. You extract the JSON key-values using [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"name"];, [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"age"], [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"gender"], [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"email"] etc.

Then your app can either show the parsed data on the screen or do other things with it.

### EDIT

Since you're using PHP as the web service language, I recommend using Symfony 2 web framework.

You'll write something like

```
// get request
$inputName = $_REQUEST['name'];

// ORM
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// find email based on name
$member = $em->getRepository('MyWebAppWebServiceBundle:Member')->findOneByName($inputName);

...

// construct JSON array
$json = array(
    'id' => $member->getId(),
    'name' => $member->getName(),
    'email' => $member->getEmail()
);

// send the response back to the user as JSON data
$response = new Response(json_encode($json));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

Alternatively, if you want scalable applications, you can use Node.js (server side Javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done step 1, and 3. In step 2, I use "sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));" to response to client, but i wonder if it reponse to the exact the client that sent request to

Comment: Thanks for your code. You use $response = new Response(json_encode($json));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response; But I cann't see where in the code, you specify the address of the recipent?

Comment: Why don't you try sending a request on your simulator and see if you get a response from your phone? I don't think a request will randomly send to someone else unless you told it to.

Comment: This link might answer your question about response target resolution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104525/how-does-a-http-response-find-its-way-to-the-correct-browser-window

Comment: Yeah, the simulator got response from web service, But i don't know for sure if the others also recieve that message

Comment: Open your browser, send a request, your simulator should not receive a response. That's one way you can test. You shouldn't need to worry about this stuff though, when they build the HTTP protocol, they already have thought of this, otherwise, when you make a Google search, the entire world would have seen what you searched for :P

Answer (score 0):

If it's a mobile site or an app, you can use jquery ajax to query your webservice, which will yield a response if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I use http post, json to send from ios client to php web service. Jquery or ajax is not relevant to this situation